# Filtering out adverts not suitable for children in Facebook Audience Network in an Android app

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I want to use Facebook Audience Network for Android app monetisation. But my app is Primarily Child-Directed. So I want to filter out ads inappropriate for children before using/publishing it. I am not able to find any such setting.

Also I found something that is mentioned below.

[Information for Child-Directed Apps and Services](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/coppa/#%25253A~%25253AtargetText%25253DYour%25252520site%2525252C%25252520app%2525252C%25252520or%25252520service%25252520is%25252520directed%25252520to%25252520children%25252520but%25252Cnot%25252520include%25252520an%25252520age%25252520gate.)

But still I am looking for something that can help me. Should I go with it or leave it?